# S3 Bucket and React native

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, expo, upload

I have a S3 and React Native project with Type Script, this project uploads images and videos from a mobile, I was uploading the image in a string (base 64), and obviously I do not visualize the image from the presigned URL of S3, some idea How can I display either image or video?, look for that solutions but use nodejs modules that are not in React Native and support problems, I am thinking of uploading the images and videos in Blob directly to S3 (or something equivalent to "File" on the web) but I have not found how to do that, what solution should I take that it is easy to upload and recover those photos and videos?

```
//photo and banner are uris
//the uri is something like 'file://<systemDirs>/image.jpg'

const photo64 = await FileSytem.readAsStringAsync(photo, {
 encoding: FileSytem.EncodingType.Base64 //or UTF-8
});       
 
const banner64 = await FileSytem.readAsStringAsync(banner, {
 encoding: FileSytem.EncodingType.Base64
});
```

And then I upload the information in the bucket

I am using **import * as FileSytem from 'expo-file-system';**, How do I upload image or video? (To only have the URL to S3 and show directly)

Try to get the base64 string, but the URL doesn't provide it directly or something similar. In case I could obtain the string, I would need to use a buffer or blob or some other Node.js module that wouldn't be available in React Native. I'll try to find a way to upload the blob or something similar as a 'File' when it's a web app. However, I'm open to any solution or recommendation

Comment: I found an npm module **react-native-aws3**, but I still don't know if it really works as expected, I have had this error: **{"headers": {}, "status": 0, "text": "Stream Closed"}**, I configured the policies and users to access S3 but I don't know if maybe I did something wrong in the configuration

Answer (score 0):

**Uploading to S3:**
To upload files (images or videos) to S3 from React Native, consider using the
AWS Amplify Storage library or the AWS SDK for JavaScript in a React Native
environment. You can use the Storage module from AWS Amplify or the aws-sdk
library (specifically the S3 module) to upload the files.

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

// Upload an image
async function uploadImage(base64Data) {
  try {
    const result = await Storage.put('imageName.jpg', base64Data, {
      contentType: 'image/jpeg' // Specify the content type
    });
    console.log('Image uploaded successfully:', result.key);
    return result.key; // Return the key (object key) for reference
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

**Retrieve Presigned URLs:**
After uploading the files, you can generate presigned URLs to access these files
directly from the S3 bucket. Presigned URLs are temporary URLs that grant
time-limited access to the files.

```
  async function getPresignedUrl(key) {
      try {
        const url = await Storage.get(key, { expires: 60 }); // Expiration time 
        in seconds
        console.log('Presigned URL:', url);
        return url;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error getting presigned URL:', error);
        throw error;
      }
    }
```